# UPDATE with use same table and row offset

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Have table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`stat` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `tarif_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `in` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `out` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `next_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Example of data:

[image]

Have next problem. How to write update query for fill `next_date` where `next_date`=`date` of next row this user(`user_id`)

Comment: so for first row user_id = 3 what value will be set for next_date ?

Comment: date from row with id=528

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it by joining the same table

```
update stat t1 
join
(
  select 
  id,date,user_id
  from stat 
)t2
on t2.user_id = t1.user_id
AND t2.id > t1.id
set t1.next_date = t2.date ;
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/823d711/1)**

Comment: I try some like this, but without join. Thx!